# SQL Server : Group By Price and Sum Amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| Id | Type | Price | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4284627 | sell | 307.800000 | 27.390000 |
| 4284640 | sell | 307.800000 | 2.670000 |
| 4284681 | buy | 307.600000 | 0.480000 |
| 4284682 | buy | 307.600000 | 1.960000 |

And I am trying to get following result: 2 rows, sum amount of same prices.

| Id | Type | Price | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4284627 | sell | 307.800000 | 30.06 |
| 4284681 | buy | 307.600000 | 2.44 |

Can anyone point me to right direction please?

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind this transformation?

Comment: Why do you need ID column in result ? it seems meaninglees since you aggregate the others.

Comment: Just looks like a `SUM` and `MIN` to me. Neither of these are particularly difficult concepts in SQL.

Comment: Reasoning is this: i need to show how many ( amount ) sell orders or buy orders in the system by the price. I don't need ID in the result but i need to order by last to first, so Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to group by `type` as well:

```
select min(id), type, price, sum(amount)
from t
group by type, price;
```

But for your question, this works:

```
select min(id), min(type), price, sum(amount)
from t
group by price;
```